# How do I store the value of an indexed list in a global variable and call at it through a formatted function?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I store the value of an index and then use that value in a formatted exec function to print me the second results of each list under class `Animal():` `Dog` list, which is what I expect to print. A simplified version of the essence of my problem along with further clarification below:

```
class Global():
    str_list = []
    current_word = ""

    adj_word = 'poofy'
    adj_int = 0

    size = 0
    pounds = 0
    dog_years = 0

class Animal():
    ##### Formatted like so:[[visual size],[pounds],[age in dog years],[almost dead]] #####
    dog = [['small', 'poofy'],[7, 45],[18, 101],[0, 1]]

input = 'dog'

def done():
    print(Global.adj_int)
    print(str(Global.size), str(Global.pounds), str(Global.dog_years))

def split_str():
    Global.str_list = input.split()

split_str()

def analyze():
    Global.current_word = Global.str_list.pop(0)

    exec(f"""if Global.adj_word in Animal.{Global.current_word}[0]:
        Global.adj_int = Animal.{Global.current_word}[0].index('{Global.adj_word}')
        Global.size = Animal.{Global.current_word}[1][{Global.adj_int}]
        Global.pounds = Animal.{Global.current_word}[2][{Global.adj_int}]
        Global.dog_years = Animal.{Global.current_word}[3][{Global.adj_int}]""")

    if len(Global.str_list) == 0:
        done()

analyze()
```

it returns:

```
1
7 18 0
```

When I expect it to return `"45 101 1"` for size, pounds, `dog_years` because I am storing the `.index` value of `'poofy'` for `Animal.dog` list in `Global.adj_int`. which in this case is `'1'`. Then I try to format the code so it uses that value to print the second values of each list but for some reason it will not print the expected results(under `def analyze():... exec(f"""...`. Does anyone have an answer to this question?? This is a much more simple version of what I originally have but produces the exact same result. when I try to use the formatted code it acts as if `adj_int = 0` when really it's `adj_int = 1` (and I know it is stored as 1 like it should be because I print adj_int at the end to check) or I am not able to format the code in this way? But I need a work around regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the string argument to `exec` is being evaluated before it is executed. So, when you are calling `exec` this is what is called:

```
 exec(f"""if Global.adj_word in Animal.dog[0]:
    Global.adj_int = Animal.{dog}[0].index('poofy')
    Global.size = Animal.dog[1][0]
    Global.pounds = Animal.dog[2][0]
    Global.dog_years = Animal.dog[3][0]""")
```

And *after* this, `Global.adj_int` becomes `1`. The control flow and the structure of your code is incredibly complex comparing to its simplicity so I would carefully rethink its design, but for a quick fix, you probably want to first execute the part that sets the `adj_int` and then the rest, like this:

```
 exec(f"""if Global.adj_word in Animal.{Global.current_word}[0]:
    Global.adj_int = Animal.{Global.current_word}[0].index('{Global.adj_word}'"""))

 exec(f"""if Global.adj_word in Animal.{Global.current_word}[0]:
    Global.size = Animal.{Global.current_word}[1][{Global.adj_int}]
    Global.pounds = Animal.{Global.current_word}[2][{Global.adj_int}]
    Global.dog_years = Animal.{Global.current_word}[3][{Global.adj_int}]""")
```

Even after stating that your program is unnecessarily complex, let me additionally point out that using a global, mutable state is a really really bad practice, which makes your programs hard to follow, maintain & debug. The same concern relates to using `exec`.

Comment: So the exec() is basically executing as a whole instead of traditionally syntax? Wow, thank you! Another question: like you mentionee I,  would very much not like to use exec() or eval() but I need to format the word into the function I.e. `if Global.adj_word in Animal.{Global.current_word}[0]:
    Global.size = Animal.{Global.current_word}[1][{Global.adj_int}]` any ideas on how to do so? I have not been able to find another way to format and execute this style of code.

Comment: I wrote that really crappy: *traditional *mentioned, I

Comment: @Zoetyc Easiest approach would be to use a dictionary. The key is the current animal, and value - a set of animal's properties. You can ask another question about it so it will be easier to discuss, separately from the issue you've had here.